# Adding images to Urban Airship Rich push composing

Tags: iphone, ios, urbanairship.com

In the rich push message i know its html format which is used .The question is i dont hav any specific server services available.Is there some ways to show images in the message without hosting it on specific servers.In other words are there any methods in html other than the image tag to show an image in html?where content is stored locally in the html page itself?or is there any other possible ways?

Language :Obj C

Answer (score 0):

I send the images in-line with the html (rich text message) - this allows the inbox to be read off-line.

You did not specify what programming language you were using, so I'll give you what I've got in php:

```
/**
 * htmlReportImageFromUrl - Takes a url to an image (png), return a html inline image in a <div/>
 *
 * @author Kent Behrends, kent@bci.com, 2012-04-12
 * @param string $url to a png image   
 * @param string $imageFormat and format that Imagick supports, default to 'png'
 * @param int $resizeImage in pixels, defualt to 48
 * @param string $altText for the image 
 * @return string html <div/> string with image data or <div>Bad Image</div>
 */
function htmlReportImageFromUrl($url, $imageFormat = "png", $resizeImage = "48", $altText = "image") {
    $image = new Imagick ();
    $f = fopen ( $url, 'rb' );
    $status = $image->readImageFile ( $f );
    fclose ( $f );
    if (! $status) return '<div>Bad Image</div>';
    $image->setImageFormat ( $imageFormat );
    $image->resizeImage ( $resizeImage, 0, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, - 1 );
    $encoded = base64_encode ( $image->getImageBlob () );
    return '<div><img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $encoded . '" alt="'.$altText.'"></div>';
}
```

An example of using this function and it's output.

```
$kentsImage = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6376f5c874dd475857c1b4c082f2e665?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG';
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h4>Sample image from gravatar.com</h4>';
$message .= '<table><tr><td>Kent</td><td>'.htmlReportImageFromUrl($kentsImage).'</td></tr></table>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
print $message;
```

You would send $message as the payload to Urban Airships AirMail url:

The formatted output, the src="data:image/png... has been truncated:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h4>Sample image from gravatar.com</h4>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Kent</td>
        <td>
          <div><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS ...</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh fgt to mention tht.This  is for obj c

Comment: @ithu-thiruvathira Your rich pushing from an iOS device or OS X ?